# Does Spirit Shield reduce Damage before or after it carries over because of Warding Bond

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, damage-reduction

The [*warding bond*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/warding-bond) spell says

> While the target is within 60 feet of you, it gains a +1 bonus to AC and saving throws, and it has resistance to all damage. Also, each time it takes damage, **you take the same amount of damage**.

Let's say the Cleric casts *warding bond* on the wizard. The wizard gets hit for 24 damage. Because the Warding Bond gives him resistance to all damage he only takes 12. Now the (Path of the Ancestral Guardian) Barbarian uses his Spirit Shield feature to reduce this damage by 6.

Does the Cleric receive the initial 12 damage or the reduced 6?

Comment: I believe this was answered in another post. This is mostly a calculation order question.   https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/91250/damage-reduction-and-damage-resistance-how-to-calculate

Comment: @ChristianGriffith thats part of the answer but also the question asks whether the cleric takes the before-reduction damage or the after-reduction damage, making it not a true duplicate (but certainly related)

Comment: While there is an order of operations question (resolved by David), the target won't actually *take* any damage until all of the various reduction types are applied, so the Cleric will receive the fully reduced amount, whatever it happens to be.

Comment: [Related question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/62821/22566)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### The cleric takes 9 damage

To start with, resistance takes effect after all other damage reductions. So the 24 damage is reduced before resistance is considered. This rule can be found in the Combat chapter of the Basic Rules:

> Resistance and then vulnerability are applied after all other modifiers to damage.

After the damage is reduced to 18 (Xd6 = 6 in this example), it is halved to 9 from the resistance granted by *warding bond.* The cleric then takes the same amount of damage:

> each time [the target] takes damage, you take the same amount of damage.