# Resistance and Parry

Tags: dnd-5e, damage-reduction

I am running a barbarian and fighter multiclass. When raging, I have resistance to all bludgeoning, piercing, and slashing damage. And the fighter Battle Master Maneuver Parry allows me to expend a superiority die to reduce damage. It is unclear in which order these would trigger. Rage halve it then Battle Master die lower it? Or Battle Master die then rage halve it? (I don't think this is stacking resistance since the Parry isn't resistance.)

Comment: What game and edition do you play?

Comment: Hi Joshua Davis, welcome to RPG.SE!  Please feel free to take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour), check out the [Help Center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) if you have further questions, and have fun!  As a general rule, it's best to tag any system-specific questions with exactly what game and edition you're asking about - if there's _any_ doubt at all, we don't try to guess, so we don't make your question less useful to you by guessing wrong.  You can use the [edit](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/142817/edit) button beneath your post to add that tag.

Comment: D and D 5th edition. Edited, thanks for the help

Comment: @JoshuaDavis Thanks for clarifying, the question will be reopened shortly :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Damage reduction and damage resistance: how to calculate?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/91250/damage-reduction-and-damage-resistance-how-to-calculate), which asks the question of what order you do these things in more generally but is the same basic mechanics

Comment: Good spot, Carcer.  @JoshuaDavis, I hope that helps ^_^ and just so you know, getting a question closed is pretty common for new users.  Duplicates happen, and rather than deleting the dupe, we link it to the one that already has a good answer, to make it easier to find that answer (since at least one person couldn't find the original question when they searched for it, or they wouldn't have asked the new one, right?)  It doesn't mean you did anything _wrong_ or anything like that; just that your Google-fu failed you this once.

Answer (score 4):

### Parry reduces the damage, then Resistance halves the remainder.

Per [DnD Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#DamageResistanceandVulnerability), Wizards of the Coast's official rules resource, "Resistance and then vulnerability are applied after all other modifiers to damage."  So you Parry the hit to deflect part of the damage, then whatever's left gets through, hits you, and gets halved by your resistance.